# Locate a directory from a relative path in ps output

Tags: process

When I executed the command to give the pid of my processes running, it gave me like this -

```
user@machineA:/$ ps -eo pid,command | grep exhibitor | grep java | grep -v grep
 1615 java -jar ./exhibitor-1.2.3/lib/exhibitor-1.2.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar --fsconfigdir /opt/exhibitor/conf --hostname machineA
```

Now I saw this path in the above output -

```
./exhibitor-1.2.3/lib/exhibitor-1.2.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

Now I am trying to understand where this folder is `./exhibitor-1.2.3/` as I am not able to find out. Does this folder on the same ubuntu machine? Is there any way to find out that directory where it is?

I am running Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file name is relative to the current directory at the time the Java process tried to access it. There's no sure way to determine that. You can look at the process's current directory:

```
ls -l /proc/1615/cwd
```

If the process still has the file open, you'll be able to easily find out where it is.

```
ls -l /proc/1615/fd
```

If you can't find the file this way because the program changed its current directory, you can try checking the parent process's current directory, if the parent process is still alive. Use `ps l 1615` to see the parent process's PID (PPID), then look at the parent process's `cwd`.

If that fails, you can use the [locate command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locate_%28Unix%29) to search for files with a certain name.

```
locate exhibitor-1.2.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

The locate command searches an index which is updated every night (or at variable times if you turn off your computer at night), so if you installed the file recently, you might not find it that way.

In desperation, you can use the `find` command to look for the file in a directory hierarchy. For example, if you suspect the file is under your home directory:

```
find ~ -name exhibitor-1.2.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

To look everywhere in the system directories:

```
find / -xdev -name exhibitor-1.2.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

Answer (score 2):

You can read the current directory of the process:

```
readlink /proc/1615/cwd
```

This will only work to determine that relative path if the process did not change it's working directory since it was executed. Another thing to note is that processes can change their command name (what is displayed in PS), so it should not be relied on.

Answer (score 0):

Use `find`

```
find / -name exhibitor-1.2.3 -type d -print
```

This will find all directories name `exhibitor-1.2.3` on your system.